# With Microsoft Playwright, how do I find an anchor tag by its text once that text becomes visible

Tags: css, playwright

The dom starts like this

```
<a>Text 1</a>
<a>Text 2</a>
<a>Text 3</a>
```

and...after some time the dom gets updated to the following

```
<a>Text 1 - updated</a>
<a>Text 2 - updated</a>
<a>Text 3 - updated</a>
```

I want to take a certain action after "Text 2" updates to "Text 2 - updated"

I've tried a handful of wrong things such as:

```
await page.locator('a[value="Text 2 - updated"]').waitFor({state: "attached"});
// then do action

await page.locator('a:contains("Text 2 - updated")').waitFor({state: "visible"});
// then do action

await page.getByRole('a', { name: "Text 2 - updated" }).waitFor({state: "visible"});
// then do action
```

Comment: There is no selector for the text contents of an element. You'd have to change an attribute/class/id/etc on the tag itself to be able to select it.

Comment: I can't change anything about the tag since I don't have access to the source code :(

Comment: Are you looking for mutationObserver?

Comment: What triggers the dom update to change the text on the element?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can using [toContainText](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locatorassertions#locator-assertions-to-contain-text) `web assertion` which auto waits for the element  to reach to certain state per set timeout.

```
const locator = page.locator('a').first();
await expect(locator).toContainText('Text 2 - updated', {timeout: 5000});
```

Comment: When I run that, I get the following error "Error: strict mode violation: locator('a') resolved to 3 elements"

Comment: That means 'Text 2 - updated' is displayed 3 times which seem incorrect anyways.

Comment: Updated the answer to pick the first element.